# This data is not editable using ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, editing, feature-class, azure

Bit of a vague one this. I've got a table in an Azure SQL database, which has been enabled as a geodatabase. I'm trying to edit this, but cannot, as I keep getting the following error whenever I try:

> This data is not editable

In true ArcGIS fashion, the detail behind the error is pretty vague, saying:

> The layer or table is in use, being edited, or otherwise unavailable
> for editing.
>
> Solution: Make sure no other users are accessing or editing the data.
> If you have other ArcGIS applications open, close them and try to edit
> the data again.
>
> In addition, you may see this error message on certain types of
> datasets that are not intended to be edited.

I have taken this down into a local geodatabase, where it can be edited. However, we do need it to stay online, within the geodatabase in Azure. As far as I know it is not versioned, and I'm certain nobody else is editing the data. ArcCatalog reports it as an SDE Feature Class.

Any idea what I can check? I'm fairly certain there's an error in how it has been set up.

Comment: Have you explored this [page](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/databases-in-the-cloud.htm#) and [this](https://community.esri.com/t5/data-management-questions/azure-sql-database-and-arcgis-experience/td-p/244412)?

Comment: Have you tried versioning the data? Is there a relationship class to another table that you might not have set permissions on?

Answer (score -1):

Turns out that I needed to register the data, and to do that it means that only ONE spatial column can be present (despite me saying which one it should use during the registration).

We had a geom (geometry) column containing polygons, and a centroid (geography) column containing points, but the centroid column was never used, so I dropped that one. After a bit of to-ing and fro-ing (taking the service down, then for some reason ArcServer said that the data source wasn't registered so had to re-register it) it started working.